# How can I list tags of a given image using docker-py?

Tags: docker, docker-image, dockerpy

Say I've the following images:

```
REPOSITORY                                 TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
docker.site.org:4000/project/my_backend    latest              d8f4b42c0cae        5 days ago          189 MB
docker.site.org:4000/project/my_backend    v1.6.1              d8f4b42c0cae        5 days ago          189 MB
docker.site.org:4000/project/my_daemon     latest              b8a28fa9fa9c        5 days ago          865 MB
docker.site.org:4000/project/my_daemon     v1.6.1              652e925c18f3        5 days ago          865 MB
docker.site.org:4000/project/my_daemon     v1.6.0              e6cff3d768d4        5 days ago          865 MB
```

#### Question

How do I list tags for the `my_daemon` image using `docker-py` to get this output (order is irrelevant) ?

```
['v1.6.1', 'v1.6.0', 'latest']
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Test

```
def test_list_available_daemons_version(self):
    images = mock.get_images()

    versions = container_services.available_versions(images, name='project/my_daemon')

    self.assertEqual(len(versions), 3)
    self.assertCountEqual(set(versions), {'latest', 'v1.6.1', 'v1.6.0'})
```

#### Solution

```
def available_versions(images=[], name='project/my_daemon'):
    versions = []

    for image in images:
        tags = image['RepoTags']
        for tag in tags:
            if name in tag:
                version = tag.split(':')[-1]
                versions.append(version)

    return versions
```

Comment: Why are you assuming the last tag in the list is the "version"?  Correct my understanding, but I thought each tag is a unique identifier for the object in a repository. If I add a tag to an image after pulling it, wouldn't that be the last tag?

Comment: I'm append the version, e.g. `v1.6.0` extracted from each tag, e.g. `foo:v1.6.0`, in the list of tags. It's been a while since I wrote this code~